# Reading all Unread Messages/ recent messages in javaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm getting an exception while inbox is fetched.I use mail.jar and javamail_1.4.1.jar. I wanted to get just list of Unread Messages. However I'm getting a Null pointer exception in "inbox.fetch(messages, fp);" Code Snippet>>>>

```
    inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
    int unreadMessageCount = inbox.getUnreadMessageCount();        
    Message messages[]                                                                                   
    = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN),false)); 
    FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();    
    fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
    //fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.FLAGS); 
    fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO); 
    //fp.add("X-     Mailer");
    inbox.fetch(messages,fp)>>>> Causes NullPointerException
```

All Suggestions would be great and helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace please? Are you sure that `messages[]` is not null?

Comment: @Jens according to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3550807/javamail-can-fetchprofile-be-used-when-searching-mails-instead-of-just-fetching?answertab=votes#tab-top),  a FetchProfile can't be used along with Folder.search, so I removed it and just using as mentioned below......            Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);      FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen,false);      Message messages[] = inbox.search(unseenFlagTerm);  Without any FetchProfile  But the ``message[]`` still comes as null, no Idea where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to upgrade to a [more recent version of JavaMail](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#Download_JavaMail_1.5.2_Release), although I don't think it has anything to do with your problem.

Are you sure there are unseen messages in your INBOX?

You're not using [POP3](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html), are you?

Please post the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) showing the results of the search.

Comment: Resolved!!!!  Apparently my mail server had 2 unread mssgs already, which was not showed explicitly in my mail client, also I was not able to locate where the extra 2 mssgs were. So I first marked all messages in my Inbox as READ ``msgs[i].setFlag(Flag.DELETED, true);``, post which it worked like a charm.  Apparently it turned out to be a mail account problem.  Thanks @Jens and @Bill Shannon.